# AngularJS: Issue with $http request - DOM not updated for jQuery function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm having a issue where calling the $http request is not updating the DOM for jQuery function call.

Please check the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SangPXBjkirCmssePVV1?p=preview)

In my code script.js, for testing purpose I have $scope.components both as global and in a function.
But when i hardcoded the json value to the global variable everything works fine. when i get the json as a $http response, the expand and collapse functionality of tree structure stops working.

Below is my code for $http request

```
$scope.init = function init() {
$http.get('treeData.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.components = data;
}).error(function(data) {

});
```

};

Please let me know what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Create a directive and put your jquery code inside the directive.

Comment: @ArnaudGueras creating directive didn't solve the issue. But, the answer that i marked works for me. Are there any drawbacks in the solution  provided by vpsingh016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your jQuery code is getting executed before getting the data from treedata.json. `$http` will create a promise so move you jQuery logic after promises is getting resolved.
 I have updated the plunker.

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/XuxO29FZUoXf84nVvjrg?p=preview][1]
```

Comment: There is a slight delay while loading the page.

Comment: It's not a delay, it is asynchronous call, thats why its returning a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You should define components first,like below:

 `$scope.components = [];`

Comment: Tried it... No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Look like the data coming back from the server is not in JSON format. By default `$http.get` accept JSON return type. Due to this your success function is not getting executed.

**Update**
You can check the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for using $http. The recommend way is to use `get` is as shown below.

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: I had validated my JSON in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/). Also, when i set the JSON to global variable it works fine.

Comment: can you try '$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback)' to call your api and see if it work... also keep alert or something in error function as well... this help to identify the correct error

Answer (score 0):

try $scope.$apply( 
    $scope.components = data
  );

Comment: I had linked the error in the previous comment. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest